Box-api get_items() folders fetch limits to 15 folders
I am trying to fetch a specific folder under thetarget_folder_name variable from my box account using get_items in box SDK. However, my code below fetches only first 15 folder names and stops rightafter. Pagination is not working as expected.
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        box_client = get_box_jwt_client()    
        target_folder_name = "my_test_folder"
        box_folder_id = get_box_folder_id(box_client, target_folder_name)
    
        if box_folder_id:
            print(f"Found folder ID: {box_folder_id}")
        else:
            print(f"Folder '{target_folder_name}' not found")
    
def get_box_folder_id(items, target_folder_name, root_folder_id="0", limit=200, offset=0):
        """
        Recursively fetches items from a Box folder in batches and returns the folder ID of the target folder.
        """
        items = box_client.folder(root_folder_id).get_items(limit=limit, offset=offset)
        for item in items:     
            if item.name == target_folder_name and item.type == 'folder':
                print(f"Folder '{target_folder_name}' found with ID: {item.id}")
                return item.id  # Return the folder ID as soon as it is found
        if len(list(items)) < limit:
            return None      
        # Fetch the next batch by updating the offset
        return get_box_folder_id(box_client, target_folder_name, root_folder_id, limit, offset + limit)

How to fix the file fetch limit issue?

could it be that in the recursion it reaches the limit of 200? Have you tried increasing this limit and seeing if it still stops at 15 folders?

yes i tried that and no luck. still same
